# How to change the HTML of the commerce shipping service form on checkout pages?

Tags: commerce

Right now, the HTML of the commerce shipping service consists  by input buttons, where you select the desired method.
I'd like to is to have it in the form of a select, and - more importantly - have no default shipping method selcted.
How to do it?

Comment: hook_form_alter is all you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by clive, You should try this:

```
function MYMODULE_form_commerce_checkout_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'commerce_checkout_form':
      ...
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you maybe point some examples?

Comment: Beginner's problems with trying to deal with this: dpm($form_id) outputs "commerce_checkout_form_checkout" rather then "commerce_checkout_form", so I guess that's what I should use?