# No default selection in a select item on commerce checkout pages using hook_form_alter

Tags: commerce

Thanks to the help I received in [my previous question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138368/how-to-change-the-html-of-the-commerce-shipping-service-form-on-checkout-pages), I was able to change the HTML of shipping service from radios to a select field. This was done, as suggested, by means of a custom module implementing `hook_form_alter`.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if ($form_id=='commerce_checkout_form_checkout') {
        $form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service']['#type']='select';
    }
}
```

Now what i need is to have an empty option ("select the proper value") in it, so that the user would be forced to actively choose one of the shipping methods. 
What I get from

```
print_r($form);
```

is

```
    [shipping_service] => Array    
                (    
                [#type] => radios    
                [#options] => Array    
                    (    
                        [deli] => Delivery : 5,00    
                        [pickup] => Pickup: 0,00
                    )
                [#ajax] => Array
                    (
                        [callback] => commerce_shipping_pane_service_details_refresh
                        [wrapper] => commerce-shipping-service-details
                    )

                [deli] => Array
                    (
                        [#description] => 
                    )

                [pickup] => Array
                    (
                        [#description] => 
                    )

                [#default_value] => deli
            )

        [service_details] => Array
            (
                [#type] => container
                [#prefix] => 

                [#suffix] => 

            )
```

I tried to tinker with dafault value, inserting another option, like

```
$form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service']['#options']['_none']='['-select-']';
$form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service']['#options']['#default_value']='['_none']';
```

(which was somewhat randomly inspired by the 'print_r' output from a taxonomy term field on the same form  but brought no results and did cause AJAX errors. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason you haven't tried to simply `unset` default value?

Comment: @Mołot I tried 
     `unset($form['commerce_payment']['payment_method']['#default_value']);`
which does not bring the desired result - actually, it does not change anything.

Comment: @Mołot   : I also  need the user to see the choice's not been made, so i need to enter a 'please choose' position.

Comment: There is a parsing error in `$form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service']['#options']['#default_value']='['_none']';`. The value is then `'_none'`, not `'[_none]'`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno  so it chould be `$form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service']['#options']['#default_value']=['none']`?

Comment: is there any recommended documentation/examples I should chceck?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

> If #required is TRUE and there is no #default_value, an empty option is added to the select control to force the user to make an active choice.

So take the default value out and make sure that the form code includes `'#required' => TRUE,`

I also read somewhere that you must use drupal_get_form() to build the output for a form otherwise the additional form processing functions will not run.  I did not use hook_form_alter() to modify shipping services but instead used hook_commerce_shipping_service_info() in a custom module to give me more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks! This seems promising, as the code gets simpler and more efficient. I erased the array modifications,  added #required, and the empty value presents itsef.       
I still do get AJAX errors when changing the select box value.

Comment: ...the AJAX errors turned out to be the effect of printing the variables to the page by AJAX! After disabling the print_r() that i used to collect the information about the arrays, they were gone. I still cannot achieve functioning checkout without the default payment/shipping selection - AJAX fails to let me past the checkout block